# Помогите разобраться с теорией по Angular (React, Vue)

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, vue.js

Я никак не могу понять некоторых базовых вещей, связанных с миром современного web'а.

Вот есть фреймворки: Angular, Vue, React. Это **frontend** или **backend** фреймворки? Вопрос, возможно, показался вам совсем глупым, но задал я его весьма обоснованно: я не понимаю, почему Angular (пока буду говорить только о нем, но в целом все сказанное справедливо и для остальных) [позиционируется](https://www.quora.com/Is-Angular-JS-front-end-or-back-end) как frontend-framework, тогда как в различных статьях упоминают MVC, роутеры и подобные вещи, которые, на мой взгляд, связаны только с сервером? Не могу я себе представить, для чего нужен роутер на стороне клиента, например.

С другой стороны, Angular устанавливается через пакетный менеджер Node'а, а Node, как известно, это сервер. Также смутило то, что он присутствует в рейтинге HotFrameworks, который, вроде бы, оценивает только backend фреймворки. Причем присутствует он там наряду с такими фреймворками, как .NET MVC, Ruby On Rails и другими, "серверность" которых не вызывает лично у меня сомнений.

Опять же с другой стороны лично видел файлы вроде `angular-min.js` на стороне клиента. В общем, я окончательно запутался и прошу помочь разобраться, кто есть кто, что есть что и для чего что нужно?

Заранее прошу прощения, если вопрос очень глупый и я упустил какую-то очевидную вещь. Спасибо.

---

Также вдогонку вопрос исключительно относительно Angular. Angular и Angular.js - это один и тот же фреймворк? Или 2 разных?

---

Полет мыслей после того, как вопрос уже был задан.

Еще меня во всей это катавасии смутило то, что все они (вроде как) выдают какие-то "компонентность" и "виртуальную DOM" за свои основные фишки. А как можно сопоставить компоненты интерфейса и какую бы то ни было DOM с сервером - понятия не имею.

Есть еще, например, express. И вот его "серверность" для меня вне сомнений, потому что там сразу понятно, какие задачи берется решить фреймворк.

То же и с ROR. Тот хоть и навязывает свою точку зрения относительно фронтенда, но, тем не менее, остается backend'овым. И еще насчет ROR. Туда, насколько я помню, тоже ввели какую-то интеграцию с React'ом и Vue. Но что за она и что с ней делать я нигде не нашел.

Comment: Это всё фронтенд. Роутер на клиенте получил спрос с распространением History API, т. е. когда клиент получил возможность изменять URL в адресной строке. А MVC вообще самостоятельная концепция, не связанная с клиент-сервером. Нет, Node.js это не сервер, а интерпретатор. Программы, выполняемые им, могут быть серверными веб-приложениями, а могут не быть. И нет, установка идёт через NPM (который написан на Node.js), который вовсе не требует, чтобы в модулях был код именно для Node.js -- модули React Native исполняются на JSCore, хоть и распространяются через NPM; и вообще, есть NPM-модули на Sass!

Comment: @D-side с роутером предельно понятно, благодарю. Насчет Node.js я прекрасно знаю, просто так выразился, мол, понятно, что это используется на стороне сервера, а не что он сам является сервером. А вот что касается NPM - это реально беда, как по мне. И удивительно, что для дел фронтендных вроде тех же Sass'ов был придуман Bower, который же успешненько загнулся.

Comment: @D-side а чего в ответ не написали? Вроде ж все по-делу.

Comment: Начал было. Потом, осознав масштаб проблемы, выписал закрывашку "слишком общий".

Comment: @D-side да вроде вполне конкретный. Frontend и feontend. И точка. Но все равно спасибо, что уделили время.

Comment: И это был бы неполный ответ, т. к. кроме этого в вопросе масса других вопросов и неточностей, которые нужно прояснять, чтобы сложилась цельная картина. И получается, что вместо распутывания конкретного заблуждения необходимо раскладывать кашу по крупинкам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Это frontend или backend фреймворки?

Конечно, фронтенд. То, что вы привыкли видеть роутеры на сервере не значит, что они не используются где-то еще. Сейчас у клиента есть полноценное API для управления адресной строкой, не говоря уж о том, что при загрузке SPA по адресу `/index.html#!/about` или даже просто `/about` ему необходимо понять, какую страницу грузить. Все эти фреймворки могут иметь серверную поддержку (например, для server side rendering), но их первоочередная задача - это работа в браузере пользователя.

> С другой стороны, Angular устанавливается через пакетный менеджер Node'а, а Node, как известно, это сервер.

node - это обычное приложение, которое, в том числе, может управлять сокетами, но де-факто это не сервер. Установка сводится к банальному скачиванию файлов, поэтому в теории вы можете устанавливать его хоть через браузер, браузером он от этого не станет.

Подытоживая, просто скажу еще раз, что это frontend-фреймворки, нацеленные в первую очередь на генерацию и работу с HTML-страницами. Их можно применять на сервере (в первую очередь, для тех же самых целей - генерации HTML), но это вторичные задачи, появившиеся из-за навязанных реальностью необходимостей вроде отдачи поисковикам готового HTML.

Comment: Ну насчет "Node - сервер" я уже в комментариях под вопросом пояснил. Просто некорректно выразился. Остается непонятной только последняя часть. Каким образом эти фреймворки, нацеленные на динамическое управление интерфейсом и представлением в общем могут корректно генерировать страницы на сервере? Ведь там даже той же самой адресной строки еще нет?

Comment: @smellyshovel она передается на сервер при запросе, и в ответ фреймворк может сгенерировать страницу ровно таким же образом, как это делает на клиенте - просто окружение будет немного другим, например, не будет `document`. Если вы посмотрите HTTP-запрос любым снифером, то первой строкой будет что-нибудь вроде `GET /about HTTP/1.1`, где `/about` как раз и является указанным путем